# Get the user's date format? (DMY, MDY, YMD)

Tags: ios, localization, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm creating a form where the user can enter their birthday with 3 UITextFields: 1 for month, 1 for day and 1 for year.  I'd like to arrange them based on the user's date format.
i.e.: [ MONTH ] [ DAY ] [ YEAR ] for American users, [ DAY ] [ MONTH ] [ YEAR ] for European users, etc.
Map of the date format by country: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Map

What's the easiest way to get that format?

Right now I'm setting the date October, 20 2000 and parsing the string.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:20];
[components setMonth:10];
[components setYear:2000];
NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"%@", [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]);
```

But I don't think it's the right thing to do since I got already too many different formats:

US: 10/20/00
FR: 20/10/00
Japan: 2000/10/20
Sweden: 2000-10-20

Comment: Why don't you provide a UIDatePicker for the user. It would be easier.

Comment: It's a product requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`.

```
NSString *base = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:base options:0 locale:locale];
```

The value of `format` will be adjusted with the right format based on the locale. The trick now is to scan `format` to see what order you find `M`, `d`, and `y`.

Comment: BUt How can I found the order of mm,dd,yy?

Comment: @user1673099 If you have a question that you can't find an answer to, please post your own question so it is given the proper attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the dateStyle of dateFormatter.

```
NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
//Based on users locale it would automatically change the display format
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: That doesn't give me the order for the fields.

Comment: @LG01 AFAIK the shortStyle is the way in which date needs to be displayed based on locales. Can you explain why you don't consider this as nice?

Comment: I want to know the order in which I should position the 3 UITextFields (1 for day, 1 for month and 1 for year) based on the user's locale.

Comment: @LG01 If you provide textField to enter date you need to do a lot of validations. It would be better if you can provide a standard DatePicker for that. It will save you the hazzle.

Comment: I know but it's a product requirement so I'll try to find an elegant solution and fall back to the date picker if needed