# Show date as per Local format

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

I want to show the date as per Local format of different country.

I got the code from here: [Get the user's date format? (DMY, MDY, YMD)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16095053/1673099)

```
NSString *base = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:base options:0 locale:locale];
```

But how can I fetch the order of `dd,mm,yyyy` from the format?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the output that your are up to? What edo you mean by "the order of dd,mm,yyyy"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you the format of the `currentLocale`:

```
NSString *dateComponents = @"ddMMyyyy";
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString* format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:locale];
```

To print a `NSDate` object in the right format for the `currentLocale` try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

NSString *dateComponents = @"ddMMyyyy";
NSString* format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:locale];

NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];

NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Current date for locale: %@", newDateString);
```

If you really want the number-order of the dd, MM and yyyy elements it can be done like the following code. It is not(!) pretty and I really think you should reconsider if it is necessary to get the order of the elements.

```
NSString *dateComponents = @"ddMMyyyy";
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString* format = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:locale];

int currentOrder = -1;
int nextIndex = 0;

int dd = -1;
int MM = -1;
int yyyy = -1;

NSString* workingSubstring;

while (dd == -1 || MM == -1 || yyyy == -1)
{
    workingSubstring = [[format substringFromIndex:nextIndex] substringToIndex:2];

    if ([workingSubstring isEqualToString:@"dd"])
    {
        dd = ++currentOrder;
        nextIndex += 3;
    }
    else if ([workingSubstring isEqualToString:@"MM"])
    {
        MM = ++currentOrder;
        nextIndex += 3;
    }
    else if ([workingSubstring isEqualToString:@"yy"])
    {
        yyyy = ++currentOrder;
        nextIndex += 5;
    }
}

NSLog(@"dd: %d, MM: %d, yyyy: %d", dd, MM, yyyy);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But you still misunderstood my question. I already implement the date format as per Local, but I want to find the order of the dd,mm,yyyy.

Comment: The format-string will contain the order of dd, MM and yyyy. If you print the format as NSLog("%@", format), you will see the format of the device's locale. Try to explain what you mean by "order" if it isn't what my code does :)

Comment: in USA, format:mm/dd/yyyy In Africa: format yyyy-MM-dd. In Aus format: dd-MM-yyyy. So, I just want know the order of d,m & y.

Comment: That is exactly what the first part of my answer does :) The `format` variable contains the format of the device's locale settings. Be aware that if you runs this in a simulator it will always looks like it is in USA.

Comment: But I want to know that which is the first dd or MM from the format it prints.

Comment: The simulator is quite capable to display locals from all over the world.

Comment: @user2526811, I guess you would have to parse the format string then. Again, what are you really tryting to archieve? There may be a smarter way to reach your final goal.

Comment: I have added a code piece, that should do what you want, but I agree with @HermannKlecker, that this seems a bit unecessary. And oops(!) on the locale settings on the Simulator. I can see it is possible to change the date format in the simulator :)